# How can i auto generate subdomains on azure from c# mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am developing an application where i want to make subdomains from my c# mvc application automatically rather than manually adding cname
is it possible? if possible then please help

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisites:**

To delegate an Azure DNS subdomain, you must first delegate your public domain to Azure DNS. Search for *Delegate a domain to Azure DNS* for instructions on how to configure your name servers for delegation. Once your domain is delegated to your Azure DNS zone, you can delegate your subdomain.

Start with creating the zone for the engineering subdomain:

```
New-AzDnsZone -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -Name engineering.contoso.com
```

Next, note the four name servers for the engineering subdomain:

```
Get-AzDnsRecordSet -ZoneName engineering.contoso.com -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -RecordType NS
```

Create an A record in the engineering zone to use for testing:

```
New-AzDnsRecordSet -ZoneName engineering.contoso.com -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -Name www -RecordType A -ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address 10.10.10.10).
```

Next, create a name server (NS) record for the engineering zone in the contoso.com zone:

Copy

```
$Records = @()
$Records += New-AzDnsRecordConfig -Nsdname <name server 1 noted previously>
$Records += New-AzDnsRecordConfig -Nsdname <name server 2 noted previously>
$Records += New-AzDnsRecordConfig -Nsdname <name server 3 noted previously>
$Records += New-AzDnsRecordConfig -Nsdname <name server 4 noted previously>
$RecordSet = New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name engineering -RecordType NS -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -TTL 3600 -ZoneName contoso.com -DnsRecords $Records
```

Use nslookup to test the delegation. Open a PowerShell window and type in `nslookup www.engineering.contoso.com`.
You should receive a non-authoritative answer showing the address 10.10.10.10.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/delegate-subdomain-ps)

Comment: Can i access PowerShell from C# ?

Comment: c# is a coding language. You dont access things from c#, you access them from the environment that you are running your .net code on. This is a powershell script which means you just open up an AZURE command line and run the script. Since it is a script you can run it automatically and update it from code. I suggest you learn more about AZURE.

Comment: I have seen that i can script on powershell using c# from this link, and have many more tutorials of running scripts on powershell through c#.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-azure-using-powershell/